# How to center buttons vertically and have a uncluttered design in Android

Tags: android

I have a very simple application in Android with a sentence with a blank, and two buttons which are possible fillings for the blank. At the bottom I have two strings saying where we are and how many answers we got right.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView android:id="@+id/sentence"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Today we meet __  to give you some good news."
  android:padding="8dp"
   />
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">


<Button android:id="@+id/leftAnswerButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="with you"
    />
<Button android:id="@+id/rightAnswerButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="with each other"
/>



</LinearLayout>

<Button android:id="@+id/nextButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Next"
android:layout_gravity="center"
/>



<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      >

<TextView android:id="@+id/progres"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Question: 3/10"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:paddingLeft="12dp"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
      android:paddingBottom="4dp"
      />
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right" android:layout_gravity="bottom">
<TextView android:id="@+id/encerts"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Correct: 2/9"
      android:paddingRight="12dp"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:layout_gravity="right"
      android:paddingBottom="4dp"
      />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

What I would like to do is to have the sentence at the top and the two possible answers centered vertically on the screen. The Next button would just below the two possible answers and the small status screen at the bottom should continue to be at the bottom.
I have tried many possibilities with the layout_ attributes and have added additional LinearLayout's, with no luck so far.

Comment: Have a look at `FrameLayout` and `layout_centerInParent` attribute.

Comment: Do you mean `RelativeLayout`? `layout_centerInParent` is for `RelativeLayout` but only centers horizontally, there appears to be no corresponding parameter for centering vertically in the parent (cf. my comment to the first proposed answer).

Comment: Oh, sorry, of course `RelativeLayout`.  `layout_centerInParent` for the child view should work - I've used it before.  Alternatively, use `android:gravity="center_vertical"§ or `android_centerVertical="true".

Comment: Yes, it worked ok after I enclosed the sentence (first `TextView`) in a `LinearLayout`. Then using `android:gravity=center_vertical` for the `LinearLayout` that includes the two buttons that are the possible answers worked. Curiously enough without the enclosing `LinearLayout` it does not work.

Comment: Next time, mark it as an answer rather than a comment. I can only mark as answer the suggestion to use `RelativeLayout` made below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your parent linearlayout for a relativelayout, then you'll be able to place everything using relative labels.

Comment: I have tried this and I get the same layout as with a `LinearLayout` with less code. The linear layout the two answers are in has `layout_centerInParent` equal to `true` but this centers horizontally and `layout_centerVertical` equal to true has no effect. Centering in the parent vertically (the parameter might be called `layout_centerVerticalInParent` if it existed) does not appear to be supported for `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Yes, it worked following this path. Please see the comments after the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

there are couple of solutions , try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sentence"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="Today we meet __  to give you some good news." />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/leftAnswerButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="with you" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/rightAnswerButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="with each other" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/nextButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Next" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/progres"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:text="Question: 3/10" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/encerts"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="12dp"
            android:text="Correct: 2/9" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

the changes is set the root element's height to wrap_content and it's layout_gravity to center_vertical
...

Comment: Not really the solution. The sentence "Today we meet __  to give you some good news." should be near the top and the two status `TextView`'s (with id's `progres` and `encerts` should be near the bottom. With your solution, everything is cluttered at the center.